# nl2br() , preg_replace , htmlspecialchars() and mysql_real_escape_string()

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have read all answers related to this but couldn't get the exact order to sanitize data

I have to input

```
<?php echo 'yes'; ?>

<?php echo 'yes' ?>
```

into a text area and submit it in database as it is with line breaks and output the code as it is with line breaks just as stackoverflow is doing.

output comes like this

```
<?php echo \'yes\'; ?>\r\n\r\n<?php echo \'yes\'; ?>
```

note : htmlspecialchars() is outputting the exact code but without line breaks ...

nl2br() is not taking /r and /n as line breaks

Comment: Use `mysql_real_escape_string` when inserting the data into the database and `htmlspecialchars` and then `nl2br` when printing the data in an HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the below functions when inserting data

```
 $unwanted = array("-", "_", "+"," ", etc .. );
 $yourVariable = str_replace($unwanted, "NULL", $yourVariable);
```

or

```
trim($yourVariable);
```

This function returns a string with whitespace stripped from the beginning and end or yourVariable